# How to use OSGI in Java EE and GlassFish?

Tags: java, glassfish, osgi

I have an application (implemented with JPA, EJB, JSF and PrimeFaces).

I'd like to convert this application to an OSGI bundle, but I don't know how to start with *OSGI in GlassFish.

Comment: You are aware that OSGI-conversion is a non-trivial task?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great resource [1] for understanding OSGI concept.

[1] http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html

Comment: please go through the page number 14 & get some idea for OSGI & J2EE

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good start

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/osgi.htm

Fortunately glassfish has pretty good support for JEE in OSGi. So your task is a bit simpler than for other OSGi containers. Still keep in mind like dns pointer out above that  such a migration can be quite a challenge. So your best bet is to get an external OSGi expert on the team.